# Show that $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)$ can be identified with the set of embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb C$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I would be grateful if someone could help me demonstrate the following easy fact. 
Let $K$ be a number field which is Galois over $\mathbb Q$ and $\tau_0:K\hookrightarrow \mathbb C$ a *fixed* $\mathbb Q$-embedding of $K$.

I want to show that there is a *bijection* between the sets $S:=\{\sigma\}_{\sigma\in \operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)}$ and $T:=\{\tau:K\hookrightarrow \mathbb C\}$.

The map from I consider from $S$ to $T$ is $\sigma\mapsto \tau_0\circ \sigma$.

For the inverse map I'd like to write $\tau_1\mapsto \tau_0^{-1}\circ \tau_1$ since then $\tau_1=\tau_0\circ (\tau_0^{-1}\circ \tau_1)$. If the composite map inside the brackets belongs to $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)$ then I would be done.

But the problem is that $\tau_1(K)$ may *not* be equal to $\tau_0(K)$ as sets  (as already explained on SE [Isomorphic subfields of $\mathbb C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766908/isomorphic-subfields-of-mathbb-c) ) so that I cannot see how the map $\tau_0^{-1}\circ \tau_1$ can be defined.

I'd be grateful for corrections or a different argument for the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows automatically from one of the equivalent definitions of *normal extension*: $\;K/E\;$ is normal iff every injection $\;K\to\overline E\;$ is in fact an $\;E\,-$ automorphism of $\;K\;$ , with $\;\overline E\;$ a fixed algebraic closure  of $\;E\;$ .

Thus, Gal$\,(K/\Bbb Q)\;$ is the set of all $\;\Bbb Q\,-$ automorphism of $\;K\;$, and since the extension is Galois and thus normal this is the same as the set of all $\;\Bbb Q\,-$ embeddings $\;K\to\overline Q\subset\Bbb C\;$